# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre "suficiente" y "lo suficiente"?

Tags: pronombres, clíticos

What is the function of `lo` in the following sentence:

> Perdimos porque no nos concentramos **lo** suficiente

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Suficiente" is an adjective, and as such determines a noun:

> No queda **suficiente comida**.

There is a special case that can also determine a verb: when it precedes by a neutral article "lo" (*quantitative lo*) and works as an adverb of quantity. This situation occurs only with 5 adjectives:

> No nos concentramos **lo suficiente**
>
> No traes **lo necesario**
>
> Traje solo **lo imprescindible**
>
> Compré **lo conveniente**
>
> Vale **lo justo**

Note: this answer only applies to adjectives indicated (*suficiente, necesario, conveniente, imprescindible* y *justo*). In any other case "lo" is a nominalizer, as noted in the response of Carlos Alejo.

Comment: +1 This answer is correct, but note this construction applies not only to these five adjectives, but also to many others such as *Trabaja lo indecible, lo convenido, lo normal, lo establecido, lo máximo, lo mínimo, lo insospechado*, etc. (I cannot think of more examples but I'm sure there are more), as well as other constructions such as *lo nunca visto*.

Comment: @Yay: Only 5 cases indicated [lo+adjective] = adverb of quantity. Other cases, among which are those you say, [lo+adjective] or [lo+participle] = noun. For example, in _trabaja lo indecible_, "lo indecible" is direct object, "lo que no se puede decir", thus a noun. (It took me a long answer to your comment because, you see, the difference is minimal, one technicist classification, and ultimately you're right.)

Answer (score 5):

The word "lo" is the neutral definite article. It is used when you need to use the definite article to refer to an abstract concept that comes from an adjective. In essence, "lo suficiente" means "that which is sufficient". This article is always used with the adjective in singular masculine form, i.e. "lo suficiente" is grammatically correct but "lo suficientes" is not. The word "lo" can also be used with other modifiers, not just adjectives.

According to the [RAE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ESraxkH), the formal definition is:

> Ante adjetivos en masculino singular, complementos prepositivos con la preposición de u oraciones de relativo, forma sintagmas nominales definidos que denotan entidades a las que se atribuyen las propiedades descritas por tales modificadores.

In English this means:

> Before masculine singular adjectives, prepositional phrases with the preposition "de", or relatives clauses, it *(lo)* forms definite noun phrases that denote entities to which the properties described by the modifier are attributed.

Here are examples of the three types of modifiers listen in the definition:

- Adjectives: "lo sufuciente" = "that which is sufficient"
- Prepositional phrase with "de": "lo de México" = "that which has to do with Mexico"
- Relative clause: "lo que digo" = "that which I say".

So, your sentence means "We lost because we did not concentrate enough", or "we lost because we did not concentrate a sufficient amount".

Adjectives can also be turned into nouns using "el/la/los/las" if they refer to a person. In this case, the adjective agrees in gender and number with who it describes. For example, "lo bueno" means "that which is good", but "el bueno/la buena" means "the good man/woman."

Answer (score 3):

To complement the previous answer, the function of *lo* is to render the adjective into a noun. So, you can have sentences like *lo bonito siempre atrae más*, where *bonito* is an adjective rendered into a noun. It is just the compressed version of *lo que es bonito*. With your sentence is the same thing, *lo suficiente* is just *lo que era suficiente* with some words missing.

Answer (score 1):

Suficiente viene a ser cuando lo que tienes es justo lo que necesitas, ni más ni menos, por ejemplo:

> ¡suficiente!, ¡ya no peleen mas!

pero en cambio `lo suficiente`, es cuando se habla acerca de algún objeto que tenga como acción ser suficiente, en general se usa como que algún objeto pueda o no ser lo necesario, por ejemplo:

> ¿crees que la carne sea lo suficiente como para que Juan se llene el estómago?`

En el caso de `Perdimos porque no nos concentramos lo suficiente`, quiere decir que faltó concentración, como dije antes `lo suficiente` quiere decir que puede que haya faltado o exista mucho del objeto que se quiere medir si es `lo suficiente`, en tu caso concentración

Comment: En el caso de `Perdimos porque no nos concentramos lo suficiente`, quiere decir que faltó concentración, como dije antes `lo suficiente` quiere decir que puede que haya faltado o exista mucho del objeto que se quiere medir si es `lo suficiente`, es tu casa concentración

Comment: No creo que esta respuesta sea acertada, porque si yo dijera "crees que la carne sea suficiente como para que juan se llene el estómago" tendría el mismo significado, la pregunta requiere una validez para el pronombre "lo" en el caso que se use con "suficiente" y creo que no se resuelve con esta respuesta.

Comment: @archer247 Le adicioné tu comentario a *tu* respuesta. Además nota que Michiel preguntó en inglés.

Comment: @FelipeSierra Si pero en el caso de lo suficiente siempre va a ser para comparar si tiene lo necesario o no, en cambio, suficiente por si solo puede cambiar de contexto seguún la conjunción, en tu caso usando `sea` puedes  dar el mismo contexo